# 写真を保存するには

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

objective-cで撮った写真をカメラロールに新しくフォルダ（アルバム）を作って保存するには、どうすればいいと思いますか？

Answer (score 1):

本家でよく似た話題を見つけました。

> Save Photos to Custom Album in iPhones Photo Library
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954380/save-photos-to-custom-album-in-iphones-photo-library